# Doble orderBy en mis consultas laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, querybuilder, orderby

tengo un problema que me gustaria saber si es posible resolver.

Veran, tengo una consulta que me devuelve las citas medicas de una especialidad.
Dicha consulta, tiene dos campos por los que necesito ordenar

Primero, quiero que mis campos esten ordenados por medicos. Es decir, primero me mostrará todos las citas de un medico, luego del otro, vamos, ordenadas. Esto lo puedo hacer claramente con un `OrderBy`

Mi pregunta es, ¿Puedo has que en la misma consulta, las citas tambien esten ordenadas por el numero de Cita?

```
Medico 1 -> cita 1
Medico 1 -> cita 2 
Medico 1 -> cita 3
...
Medico 1 -> cita n

Medico 2 -> cita 1
Medico 2 -> cita 2 
Medico 2 -> cita 3
...
Medico 2 -> cita n

Medico 3 -> cita 1
Medico 3 -> cita 2 
Medico 3 -> cita 3
...
Medico 3 -> cita n
```

La consulta que tengo actualmente es

```
$citas = DB::table('citas')
->orderBy(citas.Medico)
->get();
```

Comment: Intenta con `->orderBy('Medico','cita')`.

Comment: Tu idea me ayudo bastante. No funciono poniendolo asi, pero poniendo otro `orderBy` y seleccionando la cita si. Si lo pongo todo dentro de un mismo orderBy tendrian que ser todos ascendentes o descendentes. No puedes controlar independientemente los dos. Pero, si, me funcionó con tu idea. Es extraño, habia probado antes y me arrojaba un error.